# Impersonation in Microsoft Teams

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to forward messages to a selected user using Microsoft Bot Framework inside Teams. 
The functionality works as expected inside Bot Emulator, but while testing it within my organization using Teams (with valid user id's)

messages are sent straight to the user as a Bot.

```
IMessageActivity newMessage = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();

newMessage.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
newMessage.From = new ChannelAccount("Impersonated User ID", "Impersonated User Name");
newMessage.Conversation = context.Activity.Conversation;
newMessage.Recipient = new ChannelAccount("Recipient ID");
//newMessage.From.Name = "Stephane Fornaroli";
newMessage.ReplyToId = context.Activity.From.Id;
newMessage.Text = text;

await context.PostAsync(newMessage);
```

This also applies to channel conversations, for forwarding message into specified channel:

```
var messagee = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConversationReference>(conversationReference).GetPostToBotMessage();
var channelData = context.Activity.ChannelData;

var message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();

message.Text = text;
message.From = new ChannelAccount("Impersonated User ID", "Impersonated User Name");

var conversationParameters = new ConversationParameters
{
    IsGroup = true,
    ChannelData = channelData,
    Activity = (Activity)message
};
var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(messagee.ServiceUrl));

await connectorClient.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(conversationParameters);
```

Comment: For clarity, are you trying to have User A send a message to the Bot, and then the bot "forward" the message to User B, but make it appear as though the message is coming from User A? If so, that's an intentional restriction in Teams to prevent a bot impersonating a person. Alternatively, you could have your Bot send it as a Bot, but with the message something like "Message from <user>: <message>"

Comment: Yes, You are correct about scenario. But then how I can use bot to dispatch calls from users A and C to forward it to User B which could answer them.

Comment: The scenario you described is correct: (User A sends a message to the Bot, and then the bot "forward" the message to User B, but make it appear as though the message is coming from User A) For which Reason is this feature locked in Teams? This scenario was possible in Skype for Business, and as Microsoft is pushing their Customers to migrate from Skype4B to Teams, we expect Teams to cover the same scenario.

Comment: MSFT doesn't want a bot to be able to impersonate a user for transparency/privacy/security reasons. I'd imagine that in SfB, this wasn't intentionally allowed. (SfB is *barely* supported by the botframework now, just FYI).

Comment: [This docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot) should help you with setting up a MS teams bot with Skype capabilities, but as it's veering off-topic, deserves its own StackOverflow question if you run into trouble.

Comment: Considering more collaborative scenario where we have team of user who could answer certain type of question and we have multiple of such teams based on type of question they handle. Bot could post your question to respective team and also [@mention User A & User B](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-channel#constructing-mentions) if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use [Graph API to send message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatthread?view=graph-rest-beta) using delegate permissions from user. Note that currently this API is in beta and only supports sending plain text message.